# Circle graph visualisation

Tags: algorithm, graph, visualization

I have graph. I need visualise it with nodes arranged in a circle. How can i khow it's possible circle visualisation without intersections of edges or not?

Comment: Smells like an NP-hard/NP-complete problem, but I could be wrong. You could try asking on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [planarity testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing) to check if a graph can be laid out on a plane without intersections.

Comment: If you allow curved edges in your drawing, all planar graphs can be laid out in a circular shape with no edge crossings. However, it may not be the best idea for visualization.  Also, for any definition of a circular layout, planarity is a necessary condition.